# How to handle error "dispatch_unknown_error" when i am trying to trigger a jenkins job with slash command build in slack

Tags: jenkins, triggers, command, slack, slash

I want to trigger my jenkins job with slash command /build, but i will get the error "dispatch_unknown_error", i checked the url in slash command configuration, the respond code is 201, is there any solution for this one?

Any solution for this issue or is there any other replaced app in slack can trigger a jenkins job with slack message?